# How to set TimeStamp with Timezone in Laravel 5 Migrate

Tags: postgresql, migration, laravel-5

I had set timestamp in migrate laravel 5, like this:

```
$table->timestamp('verify_account')->nullable();
```

But, that is no set with timezone in postgresql. I want to set timestamp with timezone in postgresql, how to do it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? What you have looks fine? What happens when you use the above? Does it break?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I had fix my problem.. I add a few code in laravel vendor directory

First step, open

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php

then, add this:

```
public function timestampz($column)
{
    return $this->addColumn('timestamptz', $column);
}
```

After that, open

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php

then, add this:

```
 protected function typeTimestamptz(Fluent $column)
    {
        return 'timestamp(0) with time zone';
    }
```

**How to use:**
In your migration file, that is like this:

```
$table->timestampz('yourcolumntimestampwithtimezone');
```

**UPDATE**

1. Create file in app/Custom, give it name CustomBlueprint.php. If you have no Custom directory, just create first.

CustomBlueprint.php :

```
namespace App\Custom;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CustomBlueprint extends Blueprint {

    public function timestampz($column)
    {
        return $this->addColumn('timestamptz', $column);
    }

}
```

2. Create CustomPgsqlGrammar.php.

CustomPgsqlGrammar.php:

```
namespace App\Custom;

use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\PostgresGrammar;

class CustomPgsqlGrammar extends PostgresGrammar {

    protected function typeTimestamptz(Fluent $column)
    {
        return 'timestamp(0) with time zone';
    }

}
```

3. In your migration file:

Don't forgot for

```
use App\Custom\CustomBlueprint;
use App\Custom\CustomPgsqlGrammar;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
```

And then add code below before

> Schema::create

```
DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar(new CustomPgsqlGrammar());
$schema = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();

$schema->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback) {
    return new CustomBlueprint($table, $callback);
});
```

4. How to use:

   $schema->create('users', function(CustomBlueprint $table) 
   {

   ```
   $table->timestampz('completing_registration');
   ```

   }

Comment: You shouldn't be overriding the core files, as you now have no way to update laravel

Comment: So, what should i do?

Answer (score 7):

There is now a `timestampsTz` function available when using Postgres. It should be available in Laravel 5.1 and above.