# How does a Laravel schema builder dateTimeTz example look?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

As it's listed on the Available Column Types section here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-columns

We can define a new column with the type `'dateTimeTz'`, however it gives little to no clue how it should look or if it's just like a standard DateTime object. I've been searching all over the places about this type, but couldn't see anything relevant.

Can somebody explain the difference between this one and `'dateTime'`?

Comment: I'm making a guess here - the value stored will contain the time zone offset, for example `+03:00` would be added to the value. When retrieved, date is parsed from the usual `Y-m-d H:i:s` format and the time zone is calculated from the offset. Since PHP's `DateTime` accepts `DateTimeZone` as a parameter, the `DateTimeZone` would be calculated from this mentioned offset. That's how I'd go about it at least.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The datetimeTz column field is actually imported from [Doctrine's datetimetz](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/types.html#datetimetz) with additional timezone information.

In general, this helps to work with PHP's Datetime object by setting the timezone information. To learn more about when and when not you should use it, you should read this https://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html

Comment: So, what I see is that storing the date with timezone altogether isn't recommended, instead I should store the timezone separately and convert everything to UTC before storing the dates in the database?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is just an option for database systems that support two different types -- datetime without timezone information and datetime with timezone information.

I'd guess that if you use the `dateTimeTz` type with a database that doesn't support it, it would fall back to `dateTime`.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557419/how-to-set-timestamp-with-timezone-in-laravel-5-migrate).